# Change background color when specific option selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want when "Park Here" clicked it outer area should be red and when "Cancel" clicked it should be green but it shows inner color red and green. Is there any method which change background color to red and green. code is here

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
       <td bgcolor="green" align="center" ><select name="place1"  >
       <option onclick="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='red' "> Park Here</option>
       <option onclick="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='green' "> Cancel </option>
       </select></td>

  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Here is output but I want outer color should be red or green like what this tag done. IS there any method? Please tell me I want outer color should be red on click not inner
[image]

Comment: check here -> https://jsfiddle.net/02pqmfgp/1

Comment: working.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code work fro me. My problem solved
Thank You +Rajesh Jangid

```
<select id="select" onchange="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = this.value">
  <option value='red'>Park here</option>
  <option value='green'>Cancel</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply with your color into value of option.Then its will apply with javascript

```js
function changing(that){
 var colors = document.getElementById('select').value;
 
that.parentNode.style.backgroundColor =colors
  
  }
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
       <td bgcolor="green" align="center" ><select id="select" name="place1"  onchange="changing(this)">
         <option value=""> select</option>
       <option value="red"> Park Here</option>
       <option value="green"> Cancel </option>
       </select></td>

  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: See with my answer Its working..Where the code not working?

Comment: its change the boundary color to black. table cell color remained green in its actual form.

Comment: I don't understand What you are expecting?..Can you post your code with in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: plz see my pic. I want to change my green color in to red when "park here" option is selected and when "Cancel" option is selected, I want to change previous red color to green.

Comment: I was updated my answer.It is ok.As per your question `park here ` select with change outer color to 'red' .But the shown below picture 'park here'  selected outer color was `green` .both case are different This  my confusion

Comment: this solution changing color of drop down list to red and green. I want outer color to red and green.

Comment: I want this output when "Park Here" clicked
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kKOVkbsa69oUKdvR0gvIg8LL-h_ZpcbZjrbe6Vst0U-uj-3KC5VSJfzwhrTp5EBqm3S-0pk=s170
I want this output when "Cancel" clicked
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nMA42N4MrCVtpweDWMFKzyhEnge1Lu0i95cetvOKDwGNba8D5gkUlQwXvYWvccE18iw4k2g=s170

Comment: See my updated Answer its should ok.If you need to change parent node color not body color right

Comment: +Rajesh Jangid code working I want exactly this 

<td bgcolor="green" align="center" ><select id="select" onchange="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = this.value">
                     <option value='red'>Park here</option>
                     <option value='green'>Cancel</option>
                        </select></td>

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the onchange event on the select node.
option will not respond to an onclick event.

Give your select an id so that you can select it by document.getElementById("yourId") inside the function.

```
<script>
  setColor = function(val) {
     var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  }
</script>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="setColor()">
    <option value"red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green </option>
</select>
```